# Magento compile error php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cli, command

I am running Magento 2. And my Magento admin is missing CSS also the below error is shown while compiling .

```
syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/InitialConfigSource.php on line 72
```

Admin Css hosted in below url

```
/store/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css
```

is showing this error

```
Compilation from source: 
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
variable @icon-external-link__content is undefined in file /home/username/public_html/store/var/view_preprocessed/css/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Analytics/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 59, column 14
57|   &:after {
58|     &:extend(.abs-icon all);
59|     content: @icon-external-link__content;
60|     font-size: @font-size__xs;
61|     vertical-align: super;
62|   }
#0 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/AlternativeSource.php(155): 
Magento\Framework\Css\PreProcessor\Adapter\Less\Processor->processContent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#1 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/AlternativeSource.php(115): 
Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\AlternativeSource->processContent('css/styles.css', '', '', 
Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\FallbackContext))
#2 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/PreprocessorStrategy.php(62): 
Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\AlternativeSource->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain))
#3 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/Pool.php(74): 
Magento\Developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\PreprocessorStrategy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain))
#4 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(152): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Pool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain))
#5 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(105): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->preProcess(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#6 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(150): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->getFile(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#7 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#8 /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#9 /home/username/public_html/store/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#10 {main}
```

After i had updated my php to 7.0. The below issue is shown on compile.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ItemRepository::getList(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria) must be compatible with Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentItemRepositoryInterface::getList(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria $searchCriteria) in /home/gs/public_html/store/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Shipment/ItemRepository.php on line 18
```

Right after the above error, i thought of updating my magento to 2.1.12 ( current version) and the composer shows the below error right after showing Generatng auto lock file

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator" was found in both "/home/username/public_html/store/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src//Framework/MockObject/Generator.php" and "/home/username/public_html/store/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src//Generator.php", the first will be used.
```

Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invocation" was found in both "/home/username/public_html/store/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src//Framework/MockObject/Invocation.php" and "/home/username/public_html/store/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src//Invocation.php", the first will be used.

Comment: in developer mode.. No issues . Only on production mode

Comment: Bad formatting perhaps? Developer mode is on the fly no compilation

Comment: i rise a magento issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14591 follow this and update your feedback

Comment: @Kanhaiyalal for opening a ticket on the same. And that was helpful. Also TimothyFrew for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

You might using PHP 5.x version

and the given line `syntax error, unexpected '?'`  because this is a new feature introduce in php 7 more info find http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

and respective css error might be came because of first error.

So better install magento 2 in php 7.x version and try if any concern are still there feel free to reply.

Comment: After i had fixed the above php issue i am getting the below error. Fatal error: Declaration of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ItemRepository::getList(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria) must be compatible with Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentItemRepositoryInterface::getList(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria $searchCriteria) in /home/username/public_html/store/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Shipment/ItemRepository.php on line 18

Comment: You'd better create a new question for that new error